# Inject table row in knockout foreach binding depending on previous & current row data

Tags: knockout.js

I have a flat array of data like the following which I'm writing to a table using a knockout foreach binding

```
Customer1 Item1 etc
Customer1 Item2
Customer1 Item3
Customer2 Item1
Customer2 Item2
Customer3 Item1
Customer3 Item2
Customer3 Item3
```

The customer name repeats so I'd like to group the data injecting an extra  element when the customer changes to produce:

```
Customer1
Item1
Item2
Item3
Customer2
Item1
Item2
Customer3
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

If I was writing the html in a loop I could check the value of the current customer against the next customer & inject the extra row if the customer changed but I don't know how to do that as the knockout template renders. I've thought about using an if binding and accessing the properties of $index + 1 but can't work out how to do that.

I realise I could re-map the data to a nested array but I don't want to do that in this case.

Edit
The table code that I've tried looks like

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: salesOrders">
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="5"><span id="nextCust" data-bind="text: CustDel" style="display:none;"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <!-- ko if: ($("#nextCust").text() != $("#currCust").text()) -->
     <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><a data-bind="attr: {href: CustUrl }"><span data-bind="text:CustDel"></span></a></td>
     </tr>
     <!-- /ko -->
     <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td><a data-bind="attr: { href: ItemUrl }"><span data-bind="    text: ItemID"></span></a></td>
        <td><span data-bind="alertSvg: Alert"></span></td>
        <td class="n" data-bind="text: Tot"></td>
        <td class="n" data-bind="numText: QxP"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="display:none;">
       <td colspan="5"><span id="currCust" data-bind="text:CustDel" style="display:none;"></span></td>
   </tr>
```

This is a bit of a nonsense as I'm trying to capture the value of the current & previous customer as if the bindings changed progressively down the page when of course they all change in one go as the next record is bound.

Somehow I need to access $data[$index-1].CustDel() (ie the previous record to the current one) and compare it with the current value of custDel but that statement doesn't work.

Comment: Please show us your code, and what you've tried so far. It's a little hard to imagine all that from just text.

Comment: You should really go with the nested array or computed solution because using an if for this is a quite a hacky solution: http://jsfiddle.net/f1mv1mn8/

Comment: Thanks nemesv, that's done it! It might be hacky but it makes rendering the table a lot easier (no nested table/misaligned columns/repeats of nested table headers etc etc)

Comment: Perhaps post the comment as an answer or close the question as to let others know it is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record nemesv provided the answer in the comments. See http://jsfiddle.net/f1mv1mn8/

```
<div data-bind="foreach: salesOrders">
    <!-- ko if: $index() == 0 || $parent.salesOrders()[$index() - 1].name != $parent.salesOrders()[$index()].name -->
    <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
    <!-- /ko -->

        <li data-bind="text: item"></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to create additional *computed* that will regroup original plain data in a manner like this (using your sample data):

```
var data = [
    { "name": "Customer1", "item": "Item1" },
    { "name": "Customer1", "item": "Item2" },
    { "name": "Customer1", "item": "Item3" },
    { "name": "Customer2", "item": "Item1" },
    { "name": "Customer2", "item": "Item2" },
    { "name": "Customer3", "item": "Item1" },
    { "name": "Customer3", "item": "Item2" },
    { "name": "Customer3", "item": "Item3" }
];


function ViewModel(data){
    this.salesOrders = ko.observableArray(data);
    this.salesOrders.groupedByName = ko.computed(function(){
        var names = {}, groups = [];
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.salesOrders(), function(row){
            var group = names[row.name];
            if (!group) {
                group = { name: row.name, items: [] };
                groups.push(group);
                names[row.name] = group;
            }
            group.items.push(row.item);
        });
        return groups;
    }, this);
}
```

According to the sample data this *computed* will return:

```
[
   {
      "name": "Customer1",
      "items": [
         "Item1",
         "Item2",
         "Item3"
      ]
   },
   {
      "name": "Customer2",
      "items": [
         "Item1",
         "Item2"
      ]
   },
   {
      "name": "Customer3",
      "items": [
         "Item1",
         "Item2",
         "Item3"
      ]
   }
]
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vagvscpv/1/

Comment: thanks f_martinez, that's an interesting way to use a ko.computed but I wanted to avoid using a nested array as it will make the html of my table too complicated.

Comment: OK, got it. So the only solution remained is to write custom binding that generates rows in a way you like.